# How to differentiate by color even and odd rows in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've been using sublime text 2 just like every other day and thought about improving a bit the readability of my code.

I'm seriously looking for a simple solution.
I'm not very familiar with advanced sublime tools (I mean, I know how to install packages but I do not know how to write one).

What would be the simples way to make it so that every 2nd row has a background color like 10% darker/lighter than the 1st ones?

Is there some good package which already has this implemented or how hard would it be to make a sublime script which does this for me?

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen anything like this in Sublime Text.

As a theme developer - I know we don't have even/odd selectors to change the colour.

You may be able to create a custom syntax with a package,but again I've never seen it.

As for readability - that is very important. I find these few settings to help with readability:

```
"line_padding_bottom": 1,
"line_padding_top": 1,
"highlight_line": true,
"highlight_modified_tabs": true,
```

As well spend some time finding the [perfect programming font](http://wesbos.com/programming-fonts/) and a [colour scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme)